# How to update optional fields if not empty in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords, codeigniter-3, change-password

So I have this form in which a user can update his information:
[image]

The problem comes when some of these inputs are optional. Let's say a user updates his email and password, then the update updates but when a user only edits his email and leave the password inputs blank the password in the database should not be updated....it currently changes the password as well even when they're empty.

Here is my HTML:

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger">'); ?>       
<?php echo form_open('users/edit/'.$item->id); ?>
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#basics" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Basics</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#aboutme" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">About Me</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <div class="tab-content">
<!-- Basics -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="basics">
            <!-- Email -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Email', 'email'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'email',
                        'id'            => 'email',
                        'maxlength'     => '150',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'value'         => $item->email,
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Avatar Image -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Avatar Image URL', 'avatar_img'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'avatar_img',
                        'id'            => 'avatar_img',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder'   => '96x96 Pixels',
                        'value'         => $item->avatar_img
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Cover Image -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Cover Img URL', 'cover_img'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'cover_img',
                        'id'            => 'cover_img',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'value'         => $item->cover_img
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Occupation -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Occupation', 'occupation'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'occupation',
                        'id'            => 'occupation',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'value'         => $item->occupation
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Website -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Website', 'website'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'website',
                        'id'            => 'website',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'value'         => $item->website
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Password', 'password'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'password',
                        'id'            => 'password',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'value'         => set_value('password'),
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_password($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password2 -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label('Confirm Password', 'password2'); ?>
                <div class="input-group date"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <?php
                    $data = array(
                        'name'          => 'password2',
                        'id'            => 'password2',
                        'class'         => 'form-control',
                        'value'         => set_value('password2'),
                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo form_password($data); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Update User', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

and here is what I have tried:

```
<?php
            $data = array(
                'email'      => $this->input->post('email'),
                'avatar_img' => $this->input->post('avatar_img'),
                'cover_img' => $this->input->post('cover_img'),
                'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation'),
                'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
                'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                'password2' => password_hash($this->input->post('password2'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            );

            if($this->input->post('password') != ''){
                $data['password'] = ($this->input->post('password') && !empty($this->input->post('password'))) ? $this->input->post('password') : NULL;
            }
            if($this->input->post('password2') != ''){
                $data['password2'] = ($this->input->post('password2') && !empty($this->input->post('password2'))) ? $this->input->post('password2') : NULL;
            }

            // Update User
            $this->User_model->update($id, $data);
?>
```

but it just don't work, so I tried making more simple:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'email'      => $this->input->post('email'),
        'avatar_img' => $this->input->post('avatar_img'),
        'cover_img' => $this->input->post('cover_img'),
        'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation'),
        'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
        'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
        'password2' => password_hash($this->input->post('password2'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
    );

    if($this->input->post('password') != ''){
$data['password2'] = password_hash($this->input->post('password2'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
    if($this->input->post('password2') != ''){
        $data['password2'] = password_hash($this->input->post('password2'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

    // Update User
    $this->User_model->update($id, $data);
?>
```

Update method in Userr model:

```
public function update($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);    
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should fetch the old data from the database then then using ternary operator to update the value!

Comment: Show your code from $this->User_model

Comment: @runningmark yes I can easily do that but it would update them with the same values over and over again., dont you think?

Comment: @slon check my updated question.

Comment: Then go with if else statement, and assign an array and finally update the updated values array!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the password(s) to be updated on database only if the password field(s) are NOT empty, do it like below:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'email'      => $this->input->post('email'),
        'avatar_img' => $this->input->post('avatar_img'),
        'cover_img' => $this->input->post('cover_img'),
        'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation'),
        'website' => $this->input->post('website')
    );

    if(trim($this->input->post('password')) != ''){
        $data['password'] = password_hash(trim($this->input->post('password')), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
    if(trim($this->input->post('password2')) != ''){
        $data['password2'] = password_hash(trim($this->input->post('password2')), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

        // Update User
        $this->User_model->update($id, $data);
?>
```

I removed "password" and "password2" from first array list and kept in condition check. I added trim in case the fields have white-spaces in it.

I hope this will work!

Comment: Damn, I've been all this morning trying to figure out a damn solution and you just made it exactly as I wanted. Thanks, dude!

Answer (score 1):

edit this code.

```
$data = array(
                'email'      => $this->input->post('email'),
                'avatar_img' => $this->input->post('avatar_img'),
                'cover_img' => $this->input->post('cover_img'),
                'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation'),
                'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
                'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                'password2' => password_hash($this->input->post('password2'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            );
```

to

```
    if(!empty($this->input->post('email'))){
       $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('avatar_img'))){
       $data['avatar_img'] = $this->input->post('avatar_img');
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('cover_img'))){
       $data['cover_img'] = $this->input->post('cover_img');
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('occupation'))){
       $data['occupation'] => $this->input->post('occupation');
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('website'))){
       $data['website'] = $this->input->post('website');
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('password'))){
       $data['password'] = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('password2'))){
       $data['password2'] = password_hash($this->input->post('password2'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that before but it did not work. Somebody already helped me but thanks for the intention tho.